# Detect column separators in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to separate in various files an initial *.txt file using awk. I got the following format.

```
inline  xline   X    Y     Horizon  Time    
1       159  806313 939258 KF2      0.80
....
81      149  805004 948030 FallRiver 0.85965
....
243     146  804252 965837 TensleepBbase 1.1862
```

In this case my separator is the fifth column (KF2,FallRiver,TensleepBbase). My idea is to iterate and break the loop when the value of the fifth column change but I don't know how to structure the algorithm in AWK.

The expected result is 3 txt files. One for each Horizon key word:

File1.txt

```
inline  xline   X    Y     Horizon  Time    
1       159  806313 939258 KF2      0.80
...
end of KF2 Horizon keyword
```

File2.txt

```
inline  xline   X    Y     Horizon  Time    
81      149  805004 948030 FallRiver 0.85965
...
end of FallRiver Horizon keyword
```

....

Thank you.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Replace all of the `...`s with real values as they are doing nothing but obfuscate your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using this input file,

```
inline  xline   X    Y     Horizon  Time    
1       159  806313 939258 KF2      0.80
2       9  806313 939258 KF2      0.80
3       59  806313 939258 KF2      0.80
81      149  805004 948030 FallRiver 0.85965
82      345  5678   948030 FallRiver 0.85965
243     146  804252 965837 TensleepBbase 1.1862
```

I would do this:

```
awk 'NR==1 { hdr=$0;next}            # Pick up column headers, and avoid other processing
           { hrz=$5;                 # Save current horizon
             if(hrz!=oldhrz){        # Check if horizon has changed
                if(length(oldhrz)>0)print "End of ",oldhrz > file
                file=++f ".txt"      # Work out name of output file
                print hdr > file     # Print column headers to new file
                oldhrz=hrz           # Remember which is the current horizon
             } 
             print > file
           }
     END   { print "End of ",hrz > file}' input.txt
```

**Output**

1.txt

```
inline  xline   X    Y     Horizon  Time
1       159  806313 939258 KF2      0.80
2       9  806313 939258 KF2      0.80
3       59  806313 939258 KF2      0.80
End of  KF2
```

2.txt

```
inline  xline   X    Y     Horizon  Time
81      149  805004 948030 FallRiver 0.85965
82      345  5678   948030 FallRiver 0.85965
End of  FallRiver
```

3.txt

```
inline  xline   X    Y     Horizon  Time
243     146  804252 965837 TensleepBbase 1.1862
End of  TensleepBbase
```

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you, I had missed one.

Answer (score 0):

Without the header, typical awk usecase

```
awk '{print > $5}' infile
```

to eliminate header

```
awk 'NR>1{print > $5}' infile
```

the output files will be missing the header though.  For handling headers,

```
awk 'NR==1{header=$0;next} !k[$5]++{print header > $5}  {print >> $5}' infile
```

it grabs the header, creates unique files by column 5 value with the header and appends the lines to the corresponding files.

If you want to use FileX.txt as filenames instead of the field values.  You can map them as well

```
awk 'NR==1{header=$0;next} !k[$5]++{f[$5]="File"++i".txt"; print header > f[$5]}  {print >> f[$5]}' infile
```

Finally, adding the footer can be done in the `END` statement by iterating over all unique entries

```
awk 'NR==1{header=$0;next} !k[$5]++{f[$5]="File"++i".txt"; print header > f[$5]}  {print >> f[$5]} END{for(t in f) print "End of "t" Horizon Keyword" >> f[t]}' infile
```

As suggested in the comments, you can replace `>>` with `>`.

Comment: You are confusing the awk meaning of `>>` with the shell meaning of `>>`. You do not need `>>` anywhere in the above script.

Answer (score 0):

It SOUNDS like all you need is:

```
awk '
NR==1 { hdr=$0; fldNr=5; fldName=$fldNr; next }
$fldNr != prev {
    if (out) {
        print "end of", prev, fldName, "keyword" > out
    }
    out="File" ++cnt ".txt"
    print hdr > out
    prev=$fldNr
}
{ print > out }
END { print "end of", prev, fldName, "keyword" > out }
' file
```

but without testable sample input/output it's an untested guess.